# Getting class of array from class object

Tags: java, reflection

I got an Object with type of class on input. How can I get array of this type stored in class?

```
private void myMethod  (Class pojo){
//come code
csvMapper.writerFor(pojoType[].class) //Somehow I need to get this pojoType[] from Class pojo, with respect for pojoType.class == polo
//
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [simple method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#arrayType()) has been added to the API as late as JDK 12:

```java
Class<?> arrayType = pojo.arrayType();
```

Before JDK 12, you needed a work-around like

```java
Class<?> arrayType = Array.newInstance(pojo, 0).getClass();
```

using the old [`Array.newInstance(Class, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,int)) method. This actually creates a zero length array of the type specified by `pojo`, then gets its `Class`.